# Refresh control begin refreshing not working in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Inside a UITableViewController subview I'm calling

```
refreshControl?.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
```

Which works fine in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, but doesn't seem to do anything when called in viewDidAppear. Is there a reason for this behaviour? I've set a breakpoint which shows the line is being hit and the refreshControl is not nil.

Comment: What is action for `.valueChanged`?

Comment: Why? What's wrong wth [`UIRefreshControl#beginRefreshing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol/1624842-beginrefreshing)?

Comment: Calling sendActions with valueChanged will call my handler:

`refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)`

Not that it matters, I could use beginRefreshing and it still doesn't work in viewDidLoad.